# "PHP Warning: var_export does not handle circular references" when devMode = true

Tags: php, devmode

When devMode is true, both the front end and admin of my site give me the PHP warning:

> "`var_export` does not handle circular references".

I've tried disabling plugins, with no luck.

Comment: Can you send a database dump over to support@buildwithcraft.com and we'll see if we can reproduce with your data? Will update the thread here with what we find.

Answer (score 2):

The current solution i know of is to change CLogFilter's default dumper from:

```
public $dumper='var_export';
```

To:

```
public $dumper='print_r';
```

It even has a comment above it:

```
/**
 * @var callable or function which will be used to dump context information.
 * Defaults to `var_export`. If you're experiencing issues with circular references
 * problem change it to `print_r`. Any kind of callable (static methods, user defined
 * functions, lambdas, etc.) could also be used.
 * @since 1.1.14
 */
```

My previous answer was criticised because I obviously wasn't clear enough. As for the age of this question, it's only 2 months old.

Note: I've told P&T about this.

Comment: Added the [logDumpMethod](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#logDumpMethod) config setting so this can be easily configured.