# var_export does not handle circular references” when devMode = true and logDumpMethod = print_r

Tags: plugin-development, error-message, error, controller, plugin-guestentries

[Here is a similar question that was asked but doesn't resolve my issue](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/php-warning-var-export-does-not-handle-circular-references-when-devmode-tru)

Question has changed, see UPDATE below

I'm new here so I couldn't just tag a comment onto this post asking this question:

I ran into a similar issue, the suggested fix does not work even with the config setting `'logDumpMethod' => 'print_r'`, as well as directly editing the CLogFilter.php file

I'm relatively knew to PHP, general web design, or any sort of CMS, and Have only been using Craft for about a month now so bare with me.

The last change I was completing was editing the guestEntries plugin to store session data using `craft()->httpSession->add($key, $value)` in the guestEntries plugin's controller. The problem persists with or without this addition. Granted that addition is probably not something I needed to try, however now I'm locked out of devmode because I get the same error as mentioned in the title.

Hopefully it's not something painfully obvious that I'm missing here.

Again, question is related to the error I receive as mentioned in the title and NOT how I should store session data or best practices (I will learn that in due time elsewhere.)

The controller along with the single line of editing I made:

```
private function _returnSuccess($entry, $faked = false)
{
    $successEvent = new GuestEntriesEvent($this, array('entry' => $entry, 'faked' => $faked));
    craft()->guestEntries->onSuccess($successEvent);

    if (craft()->request->isAjaxRequest())
    {
        $return['success']   = true;
        $return['title']     = $entry->title;
        $return['cpEditUrl'] = $entry->getCpEditUrl();
        $return['author']    = $entry->getAuthor()->getAttributes();
        $return['postDate']  = ($entry->postDate ? $entry->postDate->localeDate() : null);

        $this->returnJson($return);
    }
    else
    {
        craft()->userSession->setNotice(Craft::t('Entry saved.'));

        // TODO: Remove for 2.0
        if (isset($_POST['redirect']) && mb_strpos($_POST['redirect'], '{entryId}') !== false)
        {
            Craft::log('The {entryId} token within the ‘redirect’ param on entries/saveEntry requests has been deprecated. Use {id} instead.', LogLevel::Warning);
            $_POST['redirect'] = str_replace('{entryId}', '{id}', $_POST['redirect']);
        }
        craft()->httpSession->add('entry', $entry)//<--the only line I added
        $this->redirectToPostedUrl($entry);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Gave it another go of directly editing the CLogFilter.php by replacing `public $dumper='print_r';` AND changed the config file `'logDumpMethod' => 'print_r'` and that worked... Why? Should I not be able to just change it in the config file?